# Batch file, replace all files in directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to create batch file, that should do:
1) If file in directory exists - delete it
2) replace files from directory to destination directory 
3) delete source

This is my code:

```
IF EXIST C:\Work\testbatch\1.txt del C:\Work\testbatch\1.txt

MOVE C:\Work\testbatch C:\Work\destbatch  if you need copy folder
```

I've find how to copy all folder, but I need to replace just files to another folder and delete source folder. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MOVE "C:\Work\testbatch" "C:\Work\destbatch" /y
```

All I added was `/y` and deleted your unnecessary first line.

There is no need to test and delete the destination file. See `move /?` for help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using:
`robocopy "<SOURCE>" "<DESTINATION>" *.* /S /MOVE`

You may place it inside a batch file or use plain in CMD.

[For more info about ROBOCOPY and its options.](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)